# Spinning circle on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a code where onclick a word on left side of the page, it shows some text on right hand side of page. Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rani89/7uxHC/7/) of working code.
Now, my problem is I want to display spinning circle on page on every onclick and then show text on the right hand side of the page. My code for spinning circle is:

HTML:

```html
<div id="loading">
    <img src="http://jimpunk.net/Loading/wp-content/uploads/loading1.gif"/>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```js
function hideLoading() {
    document.getElementById("loading").style.display = 'block';
}

function showLoading() {
    document.getElementById("loading").style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

CSS:

```css
#loading {
    display: none;
}
```

Now, I don't know how to place them in my working code to get the desired result. Anybody knows the correct way of doing it?

`Desired result:` onclick "abc" on left hand side, spinning circle should be displayed for 1 sec and then "I should be printed on left side" should be displayed. Again on clicking "mno", first spinning circle should be shown for 1 sec and then text "I should be printed on left side" will be displayed. The fiddle has working version of `onclick`.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do here, but `alert` is blocking and it will block gif animations while it's displayed. Also, why are you setting `visible` in show and display to `block` in hide? Setting display to `block` won't hide your element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still confused by what you actually want here, but if you want to have the loading message disappear after one second, you should use `setTimeout`. Something like this:

```
function showAlert() {
    showLoading();
    setTimeout(hideLoading,1000);
    //Hide loading circle
    var myString = "I should be printed on left side";
    document.getElementById("two").innerHTML = myString;
}
```

But you also need to fix your "showLoading" and "hideLoading". Something like this:

```
function hideLoading() {
    document.getElementById("loading").style.display = 'none';
}

function showLoading() {
    document.getElementById("loading").style.display = 'block';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7uxHC/9/

BTW: if you want your loading gif to appear over your content, then set its `position:absolute` in css, but note that you gif has a white, rather than transparent background so it will obscure your content.

Comment: Here, on page load the loading message appears. I want the loading message to appear only when clicking the words: abc, xyz, mno.

Comment: @user2567857: So don't call `showLoading` in your `onLoad`. If you didn't want it, why'd you put it there in the first place? I updated the fiddle.

Comment: In this case the contents of my page is moving downwards. I don't want the contents to move down. I want the spinning circle to be on a side or over the current title of the page. Something like here http://support.snapfish.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4429/~/spinning-wheel-and-page-loading-problems

Comment: @user2567857: I added that to my answer already. You need to use css with `position:absolute` to take it out of the flow of the document. But now you are basically asking another question.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a single handler function on each element that will both hide and show the loading gif.  Also, it's a good idea not to use `getElementById` on every call, so save it in a variable:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
         <h1>Main Title of Web Page</h1>
Here I am trying to split the webpage into two columns and display text.</div>
    <div id="one">
        <div id="loading">
            <img src="http://support.snapfish.com/euf/assets/images/answer_images/SpinningWheel.gif" />
        </div>
        <div id="message"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="two"> <b>This is test one<br /></b>
 <b>This is test two<br /></b>

    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
var elements = {};

function loadSpanContent() {
    elements.loading.style.display = 'block'; // Show loading gif

    spanContent = this.innerHTML

    setTimeout(function () {
        elements.message.innerHTML = "I should be printed on left side - " + spanContent;
        elements.loading.style.display = 'none'; // Hide loading gif
        alert("onclick Event detected! " + spanContent);
    }, 1000);
}    

window.onload = function mydisplayArray() {
    var array = ['abc', 'xyz', 'mno'];

    elements.loading = document.getElementById("loading");
    elements.one = document.getElementById("one");
    elements.message = document.getElementById("message");

    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.innerHTML = array[i];
        span.onclick = loadSpanContent;

        one.appendChild(span);
    }
};
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nBaCJ/1/

Comment: In this case the contents of my page is moving downwards. I don't want the contents to move down. I want the spinning circle to be on a side or over the current title of the page. Something like here http://support.snapfish.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4429/~/spinning-wheel-and-page-loading-problems

Comment: You can use the gif on that example then.  Check out the new fiddle in the answer.

Answer (score -3):

Your request isn't clear.

But first, you should fix these 2 functions:

```
function hideLoading() {
    document.getElementById("loading").style.display = 'none';
}

function showLoading() {
    document.getElementById("loading").style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: The question isn't tagged with jQuery, so why should he "fix" his functions?